# Splitting Character String to Extract Date and Time

Tags: r, date, character, lubridate

I have a character string in a column of a tibble that looks like `Nov 01, 2019 8:00:41 AM CDT`.

I would like to create new columns of the mentioned column, Date and Time.

What is the best approaches into doing this? Lubridate?

```
Time <- tibble(Call = 1, Date_Time = 'Nov 01, 2019 8:00:41 AM CDT')
Time %>%
    mutate(Date_Time = mdy(`Contact Start Date/Time`))
```

I tried the code above but, my new column had nothing, but "NAs" in them.

Comment: Yes and no. This separated by date/time column into two, but how do I keep the time column as time?

Comment: What do you mean keep the time column as time? Like as a specific time object type? Adding an example of what you're trying to get would make it easier to answer

Answer (score 1):

**1)** We can use `as.POSIXct` and `as.Date` as shown. I am not sure what you want for the time but have provided a character string time below.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% mutate(x = as.POSIXct(x, format = "%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p"),
         date = as.Date(x),
         time = sub(".* ", "", x))
##                     x       date     time
## 1 2019-11-01 08:00:41 2019-11-01 08:00:41
```

**2)** The chron package can represent dates and times separately:

```
library(dplyr)
library(chron)

DF %>% 
  mutate(x = as.chron(as.character(x), format = "%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p"),
         date = dates(x),
         time = x - date)

##                     x     date     time
## 1 (11/01/19 08:00:41) 11/01/19 08:00:41
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(x = "Nov 01, 2019 8:00:41 AM CDT")
```

Comment: This community is the best. Thank you!

Comment: This community is the best. Thank you! For your second answer, I am getting 13:00:41 as my time which is 1:00pm military time, not 8:00am

Comment: I had modified the answer so please try it again.  the output is shown and in both cases I get 8 using `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.

Comment: The time column is formatted as a character. Is there a way to keep it as a time? Essentially what I am working up to is being able to aggregate this time so that I can get average call times grouped by date, person, etc.

Comment: R does have not a separate class for times but there is a times class in chron and it is used  in (2) of the answer.   You can take the mean of a times vector.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lubridate`s `mdy_hms` function to convert `Date_Time` to `POSIXct` format and then extract `Date` and `Time` using `as.Date` and `format` respectively.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

Time %>%
  mutate(Date_Time = mdy_hms(Date_Time), 
         Date = as.Date(Date_Time), 
         Time = format(Date_Time, "%T"))

#   Call Date_Time           Date       Time    
#  <dbl> <dttm>              <date>     <chr>   
#1     1 2019-11-01 08:00:41 2019-11-01 08:00:41
```

Comment: This community is the best. Thank you!