# splitting list into its components and combine to form another list in R

Tags: r, list

I have list 1:

```
l1 <- list(letters[1:26])
```

I have list 2:

```
l2 <- list(c(1:26))
```

How would I combine `l1` and `l2` into a new list `l4` with 52 elements: the first 26 elements are the elements of `l1` and the next 26 are the elements of `l2`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `c` to combine them

```
l4 <- c(l1[[1]], l2[[1]])
```

Or with `unlist`

```
l4 <- c(unlist(l1), unlist(l2))
```

Maybe you want to wrap it in list

```
l4 <- list(c(l1[[1]], l2[[1]]))
```